# Proving that $a^2+b^2\neq 3c^2$ for any positive nonzero integers $a$, $b$, and $c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm meant to prove the statement above and I chose to do so by thinking about the equation modulo $4$ and residue classes. My simplified process is below:

> $c^2$ is either the residue class $1$ (if odd) or $0$ (if even). After being multiplied by $3$, it is either the residue class $3$ or $0$.
>
> Similarly, $a^2$ and $b^2$ are either the residue classes $1$ (if odd) or $0$ (if even). Because of this, $a^2+b^2$ can never equal $3$ (which is $3c^2$'s residue class if it's odd), meaning that $a^2$ and $b^2$ must both be even so that $0 + 0 = 0$.

Where I'm lost is where to go from here. My instinct is to say that, since we ignoring the cases where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are zero, then the case above is invalid because $0$ is part of the residue class $0$, but that doesn't seem correct to me. Does anyone have any advice on where to go from here (or if I missed something in my proof?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You proved correctly that if $a,b,c\in\mathbb N$ are such that $a^2+b^2=3c^2$, then $a$, $b$ and $c$ must all be even numbers. So, you have $a=2m$, $b=2n$, and $c=2p$. But then $a^2+b^2=3c^2$ means that $m^2+n^2=3p^2$. And now you can start all over again. This is impossible, since you can't divide a positive integer by $2$ again and again and to keep always getting positive integers.

Comment: So basically the argument is that a^2+b^2=c^2 cannot be true, because they must be even but can't be divided by 2 indefinitely (and still get integer answers)?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: infinite descent on a well order.

Comment: Yes. I should have added that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $a,b,c$ all all even, cancel a 2 and repeat.